# HeaderCollection attribute in Refit is not recognized

Tags: c#, uwp, refit

In a UWP application, I am using `Refit` REST library. I need my request header to be dynamic. For that I am following below approach:

```
[Get("/users/{user}")]
Task<User> GetUser(string user, [HeaderCollection] IDictionary<string, string> headers);
```

This is giving the error
`The type or namespace name 'HeaderCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

I am using the latest ***Refit*** version ***v5.2.4***. Why is this happening? Do I need to import any additional namespace?

Comment: Looks like `[HeaderCollection]` is part of an upcoming version 6 release, it isn't in the code for the 5.2.4 tag: https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/v5.2.4/Refit/Attributes.cs

Comment: Thanks @MartinCostello, I just checked that. I will try using the preview version.